# Plotting discrete X/Y values over Seaborn heatmap

Tags: python, pandas, heatmap, seaborn

I'm trying to mark a specific X/Y coordinate on a Seaborn heatmap.  The output is plotting the correct X coordinate but is plotting the Y as zero/axis minimum. Code and its heatmap output is shown below.

```
speeds = pd.read_csv('pytest20140730.csv') 
speedspiv = pd.pivot_table(speeds, values = 'speed', index = 'road_order',
                           columns = 'tod_value', aggfunc = np.mean)
speedspiv = speedspiv.sort_index(axis=0, ascending = False)
plt.subplots(figsize=(20,15))
ax = sns.heatmap(speedspiv)
ax.scatter(414, 0.244444444, marker='*', s=100, color='yellow')
```

See yellow star on x-axis of the following image
[image]

What's up with the Y axis value not plotting correctly?

Comment: The y-axis has values between 382 and 453 but your marker  is told to be plotted at y=0.24. I wonder that it is even visible, or am I missing sth here?

Comment: I originally had it set as ax.scatter(0.24, 414) and there was no star.  When I switched to the above code, it appears that the 0.24 is now plotting correctly.  I know x-axis labels are currently a mess, but they are continuous with range of 0 to 1, so it somehow seems like the x/y switch to y/x showed progress.

Comment: What @SpghttCd says is true. Either your heatmap switched x and y coordinates, or your scatter plot has switched the x and y coordinates. Does this work: `ax.scatter(0.244444444, 414, marker='*', s=100, color='yellow') `

Comment: When I tried that, there was no star visible anywhere.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A seaborn heatmap produces a plot with x- and y-axes, which are index based, not data based. That means, even if labeled with 382...453 the y-axis goes from 0 to 71.
To test this, just print the result of `ax.get_xlim()` and `ax.get_ylim()`.

For your Problem to put a marker at a meaningful place in the heatmap, this means, that you'll have to compute the correct (fractional) indices of the x- and y- value of the marker and use these in the scatter plot:

```
x_vals = np.linspace(0, 1, 1500)    #  I don't know the real range of you x-data
x_idx = np.interp(.24, x_vals, range(len(x_vals)))
y_vals = np.arange(382, 453)
y_idx = np.interp(414, y_vals, range(len(y_vals)))

In: x_idx, y_idx
Out: (359.76, 32.0)
```

Comment: That seems like all it did was change the y-axis values to the index value, as I get the exact same plot with y-values from 71 to 0.  Star is in the same place.

Comment: And to clarify:  the point that I'm trying to plot is based on the X/Y values of the index and columns of the dataframe.

Comment: Ok, I tried with some sample data and found out, that a heatmap doesn't have axes ranges like labeled and/or with respect to the data. They are just indexed. I'll edit my answer in this direction...

Comment: Yes, that did it.  Thank you so much for taking the time to help figure this out.

Interesting revelation on heatplots/index axes.  I never would have made it there.  Your solution addressed the issue perfectly.

Comment: Follow-up...while I was cleaning/beautifying the graphic, I had a bit of an aha moment...since my scatter values must come from the set of values that make up the x/y axis for the heatmap, I used    
`speedspiv.columns.get_loc`   

to get the x-axis index and  
`speedspiv.index.get_loc`  
to get the y-axis index to use in place of your x_idx and y_idx defined above.  

Slightly simpler since my values  must be one of the column/index values from the pivot, which means I don't need to interpolate.  Again, thank you, because there's no way I would've arrived at that without your help.

Comment: Nice to hear that it helped. just as a hint, even if it's purely theoretical with regards to your resolution/amount of data: I saw, that integer indices as positions of markers lead to placements on the _corners_ of your heatmap tiles. You can look what I mean with a 10x10 sample array. Perhaps one might rather have the stars in the _middle_ of each coloured rectangle.

Comment: I caught that, too.  I didn't change anything on the x-axis since it's high-resolution with 1440 data points.  I did adjust the marker on the y-axis (integers) by simply taking index and subtracting 0.5, then using that for the y-value in the ax.scatter.